# Laravel: Unable to show image from database in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am new with laravel.
I am tried to show an image from database to the user page with laravel.
and also with public folder to storage folder.
code,
 this is the function  for getting data from database

```
         public function index()
           {   
                $posts = post::all();
                 return view('admin.post.show', compact('posts'));
            }
```

and this is for get image from

```
 @section('bg-img',Storage::disk('local')->url('$posts->image'))
```

my table name is'posts'

after that when i reload my page, i saw my image filed is blank but i do not get any error.

Comment: Remove the quotes from within your url(). It's reading `$posts->image` as a literal string instead of passing in the value.

Comment: do note that the url() accepts a path to a file, so because its stored in the variable posts then do this url($posts->image)

Comment: Thank you brother, now it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the reference to the url as a string.

Change it to:

`@section('bg-img',Storage::disk('local')->url($posts->image))`